# Height of Tree BST Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I tried debugging my code for getting the height of a tree using a 2d array but I am getting an error when I run it. Here is the error. We are not allowed to use classes for this lab and I am very new to manipulating 2d lists.

Any help would be really appreciated :)

error output
[image: error]

Code below

```
def index_of_node(node_id,l): 
    for i in range(0,len(l)):  # loop will match the first element of every Node List
        if l[i][0]==node_id:
            return i


def max_height(Node):
    print(Node[2])
    if Node[0]==0: # if first element of Node list means node_id ==0 then it is null node
        return 0
    if Node[1]==0 and Node[2]==0: #error is here if second and third element of Node list is 0 then Node is leaf node.
        return 1
     else:
        left_index=index_of_node(Node[1],l) # finding  index of Left child Node's Node list
        right_index=index_of_node(Node[2],l) # finding  index of right child Node's Node list
    
        return max(max_height(l[left_index]),max_height(l[right_index])) + 1

l=[[1,2,3],[2,4,5],[4,0,0],[5,0,0],[3,0,6],[6,0,0]]
   

v=max_height(l[0])
print(v)
```

Comment: It does not look like you have put all your code in the question. In your error you have return statements that are not in your definition of max_height

Comment: Right, the code you showed us is not the code with the error.  You can see that either `left_index` or `right_index` is None.

Comment: sorry about that added the missing code